# Display Block on Custom Admin Page

Tags: admin, adminhtml, controllers, admin-controller

This should be a fairly easy one, I hope. I've looked over Alan Storm's tutorial on the topic a hundred times, but still can't figure out what I'm missing. I just want to get my custom admin page to hit my controller's indexAction(), where I will then be rendering my layout, etc. For this question I'm just looking for an answer that hits my controller die statement when I click on my page in the admin.

Have already made sure:

1. cache is cleared
2. module is enabled and working, overall

Here's the relevant code:

app/code/local/Company/MyModule/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_MyModule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Company_MyModule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Company_MyModule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_MyModule_Adminhtml</mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <mymodule module="mymodule">
                <title>My Custom Page</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/MyModule/homepage/index</action>
            </mymodule>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
                            <title>MyModule</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <mymodulebackend translate="title" module="mymodule">
                                    <title>My Custom Page</title>
                                </mymodulebackend>
                            </children>
                        </mymodule>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/MyModule/controllers/Adminhtml/MyModule/HomepageController.php:

```
<?php
die();
class Company_MyModule_Adminhtml_MyModule_HomepageController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Just a test action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die('here');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have wrong in `action` tag when calling to your menu.

```
           <menu>
             <mymodule module="mymodule">
                <title>My Custom Page</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/homepage/index</action>
            </mymodule>
          </menu>
```

Your controller should reside in:

```
app/code/local/Company/controllers/Adminhtml/HomepageController.php
```

**UPDATE**

Just remove "MyModule" folder and place your `Homepagecontroller.php` inside `Adminhtml` folder.

**[Off topic a little]**

[I also have recommendation if you allow it. Not that I question @AlanStorm's authority (I would never do that :D ), for consistency reasons I think it's best yo put your admin controllers inside an Adminhtml folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12054/how-to-make-a-namespaced-admin-controller#answer-12055).

Comment: Did indeed have the names mixed up. I've updated my code above based on your answer. Unfortunately I'm still getting a 404

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: This is odd, I now get a 200 response and a white page, with no output (doesn't have the contents of my die). I set a breakpoint in xdebug and have confirmed it is not hitting that die statement. Very odd.

Comment: That is because you have `die()` (2 places) in your controller. Simply comment them.

Comment: Brillaint. Thank you so much! You've been very helpful :)

Comment: Block/Adminhtml/Interface or Adminhtml/Block/Interface? Both seem to work but the second one seems to be more what it's making - it's inside adminhtml